# How to hide grid lines in VS2019 XAML designer (UWP)?

Tags: c#, uwp

When you add some rows and columns to the Grid panel, Visual Studio 2019 will shows some layout indication lines in the XAML Designer view by default, this can interfere with my sight in some cases.

Is there a way to close it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Click into the XAML Design View
2. In the menu you will have an entry "Design"

[image: Design Menu]

3. Deactivate `Show Handles`